# Lettuce client not able to detect Redis failure immediately

Tags: redis, timeout, failover, lettuce, cache-failover

I have a latency sensitive application which uses Lettuce client to connect to an AWS ElastiCache Redis cluster. If there is a cache miss, it goes to ElasticSearch for getting the required data.

I am trying out a failover scenario where I delete the redis cluster and bring it back to check where the redis failure is detected and whther it reconnects once it is brought back.
I have set up two timeouts:

- socket timeout = 500ms
- command timeout = 100ms

During the time redis is down, instead of returning a connection failure immediately, it is waiting for a very long time >3s to get a failure. Ideally I would expect it to detect the failure immediately and go to the original DB for the required data. This is defeating the purpose of having a cache. It is slowing the service down beyond the acceptable range.

Once the redis cluster is up and running, it reconnects shortly.

I tried setting up the timeouts and expected those to kick in and detect the failure within an acceptable time.